# How to convert a model to a proper json response in java

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have a table name tableName with column id and name and i want to display them into a proper response in json , so i have created a model with Getter and Setter and i am using this model as a response at one place but the response is coming like 
"com.package.model.TableName@7cdfafef like this , what should i do ? , i have jackson bind and all even i have tried putting annotation such as @JsonRawValue  @JsonCreator and all , if i convert the json into string using GSON library then i get "\" escape characters in my response which i don't want

Comment: in your model just use `toString()` method, you'll get the proper response `@Override
    public String toString() { 
        //return statement 
    } `

Comment: Using `toString()` for application logic is a very bad idea.

Comment: I fail to see how anyone can answer this without seeing some code.

Comment: @AlanHay is right. or better why dont you put some reproducer to gitlab or github and then we can test and see what is going on.